# I have Dataframe Spark and I want to generate Ngrams but the way gensim bigram model does it

Tags: apache-spark, text, nlp, n-gram, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I have a text dataframe (tweets), I am using Spark for high volume data handling and I want to generate Bigrams in the same way as Gensim bigrams models do. I have been using Spark NLP for preprocessing the texts but the Bigrams generation with NgramGenerator performs it with all the words in the text and I want it to be considered a Bigram only when a sequence of words is continuously repeated throughout the texts(Gensim). It would be nice if it can be done with Spark NLP tool. If not, Spark MLlib would work for me, the important thing is that we keep the Spark context.

In the context of Gensim, "bigrams" refers to a technique for detecting and working with sequences of two consecutive words, rather than individual words.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me, thanks.

I tried with SparkNLP's NGramGenerator function but the Ngrams generation is done with all the words of each text.

```
ngrams = NGramGenerator() \
        .setInputCols(["lemmatized"]) \
        .setOutputCol("ngrams") \
        .setN(2) \
        .setEnableCumulative(False)\
        .setDelimiter("_")
```

---

I tried this way using UDF with gensim but it is not correct, because the process would be done by chuck(row) and gensim uses the whole column to define the bigrams.

```
from gensim.models import Phrases
from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser

def generate_bigrams(tokens):
    bigram = Phrases(tokens, min_count=5, threshold=100)
    bigram_phraser = Phraser(bigram)
    return list(bigram_phraser[tokens])

generate_bigrams_udf = udf(generate_bigrams, ArrayType(StringType()))
tweets_bigrams = process.withColumn("bigrams", generate_bigrams_udf(process["lemmatized"]))
```

Comment: The `gensim.models.Phrases` class does not appear to be trivially parallelizable given its reliance on updating class state.

I don't think you will be able to accomplish this task using the interfaces provided. Would need to write a new version of `Phrases` that supports parallel computation of algorithm substeps.

Comment: Any idea how I could parallelize this gensim process?
The other thing is that it doesn't necessarily have to be with Gensim. I'm working with Spark and would like to perform Bigramas creation in the same way that Gensim models do(In the context of Gensim, "bigramas" refers to a technique for detecting and working with sequences of two consecutive words, rather than single words), but using Spark. It doesn't matter the form, just that it stays in the Spark environment.